# How to proportionately size using UIStackView?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

I'm using a horizontal UIStackView to place an image on the left and text on the right. I want to make the image 1/3 size and the text 2/3 of the table row. I tried using content hugging and resistance, but it's not sizing it right. In an iPhone, I like the image 100px wide but want to use proportions instead. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a width constraint on the `UIImageView` that is equal to the width of the `UIStackView` with a `.multiplier` of 1/3. Then do the same thing for your `UILabel` but with a `.multiplier` of 2/3